# Named character vectors and par() in R plots

Tags: r, plot, par

I'm trying to use a named character vector to hold a custom color palette, so I can say, e.g. palette['red'] instead of repeating "#dc322f" all over the place.

However, I don't seem to be able to use an element of that vector as an argument to `par()` (though it can be used elsewhere).

Here's an example. It'll create a graph with green dots, but the par() call fails and the background is white. Note that I *can* set parameters using the palette vector from within the `plot()` call:

```
> palette <- c('#002b36','#dc322f','#859900')
> names(palette) <- c('black','red','green')
> par(bg=palette['red'])                                                                                                                                
Warning message:
In par(bg = palette["red"]) : "bg.red" is not a graphical parameter
> plot(1:10,1:10,col=palette['green'])
> # (White graph with green dots appears)
```

When I use a named *numeric* vector, however, it works:

```
> palette <- 1:3                                                                                                                                          
> names(palette) <- c('black','red','green')                                                                                                              
> par(bg=palette['red'])                                                                                                                             
> # (no error here -- it worked.)
> plot(1:10,1:10,col=palette['green'])
> # (Red graph with green dots appears)
```

I am fairly new to R, and it seems that I might be missing something fundamental. Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unname`, so that the item passed to `par` is just the character vector defining the colour, not a named element

```
palette <- c('#002b36','#dc322f','#859900')
names(palette) <- c('black','red','green')
par(bg=unname(palette['red'])) 
plot(1:10,1:10,col=palette['green'])
```

[image]

As to why?

within `par`, if all the arguments are character vectors then

```
if (all(unlist(lapply(args, is.character)))) 
            args <- as.list(unlist(args))
```

The way `as.list(unlist(args))` works if args is a named character vector is

```
args <- list(bg = palette['red'])
as.list(unlist(args))
$bg.red
[1] "#dc322f"
```

and `bg.red` is not a valid `par`.

if the line were something like

```
setNames(as.list(unlist(args, use.names = F)), names(args))
```

then it might work in some cases (although not if any of the named elements of `arg` had length >1)

Comment: A good answer with a good explanation to a good question with a good explanation. Good.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense, and it worked, and, as I suspected, the answer did provide good insight into the fundamentals.